# Prime numbers between two given integers

Tags: c++, primes

This is my code for finding prime numbers between two integers. It compiles alright but giving a runtime error SIGXFSZ on codechef.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long n,m;
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>m>>n;
        for(long long j=m;j<=n;j++)
            for(long long i=2;i<=sqrt(j);i++)
                if(j%i==0)
                    break;
                else cout<<j<<"\n";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the inputs for t, n, m?

Comment: Making a [mcve] would make your question clearer, and could help you solve this problem by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you are wrong on logic.

According to my understanding, you are supposed to print the prime numbers between two numbers.

But your code has logical errors.

1) Code doesn't consider 2 and 3 as prime numbers.

Say, `m = 1`, `n = 10`. For `j = 2, 3`, the inner loop won't execute even for the single time. Hence, the output won't be shown to be user.

2) `else cout<<j<<"\n";` statement is placed incorrectly as it will lead to prime numbers getting printed multiple times and some composite numbers also.

Example:

For `j = 11`, this code will print `11` twice (`for i = 2, 3`).

For `j = 15`, this code will print `15` once (`for i = 2`) though it is a composite number.

Answer (score 0):

You've underexplained your problem and underwritten your code.  Your program takes two separate inputs: first, the number of trials to perform; second, two numbers indicating the start and stop of an individual trial.

Your code logic is incorrect and incomplete.  If you were to use braces consistently, this might be clear.  The innermost loop needs to fail on non- prime but only it's failure to `break` signals a prime, so there can't be one unless the loop completes.  The location where you declare a prime is incorrect.  To properly deal with this situation requires some sort of flag variable or other fix to emulate labelled loops:

```
int main() {
    int trials;

    cin >> trials;

    while (trials--)
    {
        long long start, stop;

        cin >> start >> stop;

        for (long long number = start; number <= stop; number++)
        {
            if (number < 2 || (number % 2 == 0 && number != 2))
            {
                continue;
            }

            bool prime = true;

            for (long long odd = 3; odd * odd <= number; odd += 2)
            {
                if (number % odd == 0)
                {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (prime)
            {
                cout << number << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code takes the approach that it's simplest to deal with even numbers and two as a special case and focus on looping over the odd numbers.

Answer (score -1):

This is basically "exceeded file size", which means that the output file is having size larger than the allowed size.

Please do check the output file size of your program.